# What is the word for a system that has been aged and thorougly tested under all scenarios?

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples:

Imagine you are building a log cabin. You want your log cabin to be based on proven architectural design that has performed through all sorts of different weather and climates.  The design of this cabin could be called: ?????????

I need to generate images for a work assignment. I want to use an existing software that has proven itself to create high quality images under all types of different scenarios; the type an expert would use.  That system could be described in one word with:  ?????

Comment: You mention the word "proven" multiple times. That's the word I would use. "This is a proven design."

Comment: Yeah, I thought about proven too, probably why I used it so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tech field, we call such proven, tried-and-true software **robust**.

A robust system is based on proven, thoroughly tested design and can continue operation despite faulty input. Thorough testing needs to be performed to establish robustness.

> In computer science, **robustness is the ability of a computer system to cope with errors during execution**. Robustness can also be defined as the **ability of an algorithm to continue operating despite abnormalities** in input, calculations, etc.
>
> Formal techniques, such as fuzz testing, are essential to showing robustness since this type of testing involves invalid or unexpected inputs. Alternatively, fault injection can be used to test robustness.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_%28computer_science%29

Edit: Robustness is not to be confused with [fault-tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_tolerance). A robust system remains consistent when fed *inconsistent input*, whereas a fault-tolerant system remains consistent in an *inconsistent environment*.

Comment: @WillBriggs Thanks for your previous comment, you're right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: ROBUST!!  Thats it, thats the one I was looking for.  It is for software so that makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelBowers Glad I could help. Also, here's a search for phrases "robust image software" and "robust image editor" rolled into one: https://www.google.com/search?q="robust+image+software+OR+editor" It mentions GIMP, Photoshop, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**mature**

[Mature technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mature_technology)
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia

A mature technology is a technology that has been in use for long enough that most of its initial faults and inherent problems have been removed or reduced by further development. In some contexts, it may also refer to technology that has not seen widespread use, but whose scientific background is well understood.

Answer (score 0):

I might use the term **'commercial-grade'** or **'industrial-grade'** to convey that your design meets whatever is required of it in your field.

Comment: I like this one, although not quite what I was looking for.  'Enterprise-grade' could be used in the right context.

Answer (score 0):

The system has **proven track records**.

> Example: The best guide to good commercial software is a proven track
>   record of effective use by a number of clients

You may also refer to application **reliability** or to a "reliable" system/software.

> definition of *reliable*: able to be trusted to do or provide what is
>   needed; likely to be true or correct